# Irreducible factors over $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

The question is this: What is the number and degrees of the irreducible factors of $f(x)=x^{11}+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}[x]$, for $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Thoughts:

I know that the elements of $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ are precisely roots of the polynomial $x^{2^n}-x$ over $\mathbb{F}_2.$ 
Next, if $n=1$ then obviously $f(1)=0$, so that $f(x)=(x+1)g(x)$ where $\deg g(x)=10$.

One approach would be to figure out the degree of the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$, but I'm not really sure how to do this since $2^n$ is not a prime if $n>1$. (I can do it if $n=1$, which i also think is the only case where $f(x)$ is reducible).

Next, I can show that $f(x)$ cannot have any roots in $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$, for $n>1$.

Suppose that $f(a)=0;$ that is, $a^{11}\equiv -1\mod 2^n$, and so also $a^{22}\equiv 1\mod 2.$

Since $a\in \mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ it follows that $a^{2^n-1}\equiv 1\mod 2$, as well.

So, it follows that $22|2^n-1$. That is, there is some $m$ such that $2^n-1=2(11m)$, which is not possible for $n>1$ since $2^n-1$ is odd.

So, this only tells us that $f(x)$ does not have a linear factor in $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}[x]$, but not sure how to proceed from here?

Thanks!

Comment: I think i got it! I'll add an edit to my original post.

Comment: $f(-1)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, so indeed it has a root. There is something off with your proof beginning at the line where you introduce $a^{2^n-1}$.

Comment: You are correct. I guess I want to say that $a=-1$ is the only root. I think the rest of the argument is still correct since $2^n-1$ is odd so $a=-1$ would always work for all $n$ as you pointed out.

Comment: It might be true, that $-1$ is the only root, but the reasoning is still off. Why $a^{2^n-1}\equiv 1$ and how does this imply $22\mid 2^n-1$?

Comment: Well, I'm supposing that $a\in \mathbb{F}_{2^n}.$ We know that the elements of $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ then are precisely the roots of the polynomial $x^{2^n}-x$ over $\mathbb{F}_2,$ hence that congruence! Recall that $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ is the splitting field over $\mathbb{F}_2$ of the polynomial $x^{2^n}-x.$

Comment: And the implication that $22|2^n-1$ comes from the fact that the order of the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ is $2^n-1$, and thus the order of $a$ must divide it.

Comment: Okay, the first part seems right (you should exclude $a=0$ to obtain $a^{2^n-1}\equiv 1$), for the second part: Why is $22$ the order of $a$?

Comment: Because $a^{22}\equiv 1\mod 2.$ So, we at least know it should divide the order of the multiplicative group. If it's not $22$ then it should be either $2$ or $11$. But it cannot be $11$, and the same argument would still work if it were $2$.

Comment: Well the order of $a$ is $1$ (since $a\neq 0$ and there are only two elements mod $2$). You have two equations of the form $a^k=1$, all you can get from that, is that the order divides both $k$'s, so $1$ divides both $k$'s. (Hint: You loose to much information by going from mod $2^k$ to mod $2$)

Comment: But $a$ is not in $F_2$ it is in $F_{2^n}$.But I see that I should still not just move from $2^k$ to $2.$

Comment: The field $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ has characteristic two. In there $-1=1$, so you are looking for eleventh roots of unity.

Comment: The smallest power of $2$ with the property $2^n\equiv1\pmod{11}$ is $n=10$. One of the basic properties of finite fields is that their multiplicative groups are cyclic. The multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_{2^{10}}$ is cyclic of order $2^{10}-1=1023$, which is a multiple of $11$ ( follows also from Little Fermat). So the splitting field of $x^{11}+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ is $\mathbb{F}_{1024}$. It follows that the splitting fiel of $x^{11}+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ os $\mathbb{F}_{2^{m}}$, where $m=l.c.m.(10,n).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because we are in characteristic two, we have the factorization
$$
f(x)=x^{11}+1=(x+1)(x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)
$$
over the prime field $\mathbb{F}_2$. The question really is about the factorization of that degree ten cyclotomic polynomial $\phi_{11}(x)$. Its roots are eleventh primitive roots of unity. If $\beta$ is one of them (in some extension field $\mathbb{F}_{2^t}$, then the others are $\beta^j,j=2,3,\ldots,10.$

The first thing we see is that $\phi_{11}(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$. This is because if $m(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\beta$, then for any root $\gamma$ of $m(x)$ we also have that its Frobenius conjugate $\gamma^2$ is also a root. (If you haven't seen the Frobenius automorphism yet, then ask.) So $m(x)$ necessarily has, in addition $\beta$ also
$\beta^2$, $\beta^4$, $\beta^8$, $\beta^{16}=\beta^{11+5}=\beta^5$ et cetera as roots. Because $2$ generates the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_{11}^*$ (check this if you haven't seen it!), we see that all the primitive eleventh roots of unity must be zeros of $m(x)$, and thus $m(x)=\phi_{11}(x)$. The claim follows.

So all the roots $\beta^j, j=1,2,\ldots,10,$ are in an extension of degree ten, i.e. in the field $\mathbb{F}_{1024}$. Therefore the splitting field of $\phi_{11}(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ is the compositum of $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{1024}$, or the field $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$ where $m$ is the least common multiple of $n$ and $10$. After all, this is the smallest field that contains the field $\mathbb{F}_{1024}$ as well as the field $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$.
A consequence of this is that $\phi_{11}(x)$ remains irreducible over
$\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ whenever $\gcd(n,10)=1$.

A few words about the factors of $\phi_{11}(x)$ in the cases $\gcd(n,10)>1$. When we study the minimal polynomial $m_{j,n}(x)$ of $\beta^j$ over $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ the above rule changes to the form: if $\gamma$ is a zero of $m_{j,n}(x)$, then the element
$\gamma^{2^n}$ is also a zero of $m_{j,n}(x)$. For example over $\mathbb{F}_4$ we see that the zeros of $m_{1,2}(x)$ are
$$
\beta, \beta^4, \beta^{16}=\beta^5, \beta^{5\cdot4}=\beta^9, \beta^{9\cdot4}=\beta^3,
$$
but we stop here, because $\beta^{3\cdot4}=\beta$. So 
$$
m_{1,2}(x)=(x-\beta)(x-\beta^4)(x-\beta^5)(x-\beta^9)(x-\beta^3)
$$
has coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_{4}$ and is thus a quintic factor of $\phi_{11}(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_{4}$. The other factor $m_{-1,2}(x)$ is the reciprocal polynomial of $m_{1,2}(x)$, i.e. its zeros are the inverses of those of $m_{1,2}(x)$. In light of the above, the factorization of $\phi_{11}(x)$ in to irreducibles over $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ is $\phi_{11}=m_{1,2} m_{-1,2}$ whenever
$\gcd(n,10)=2$.

Of course, when $10\mid n$, the polynomial $\phi_{11}(x)$ splits into linear factors over $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$.

The remaining case is that of $\gcd(n,10)=5$. Because $(\beta^j)^{32}=\beta^{-j}$,
the polynomial
$$
m_{j,5}(x)=(x-\beta^j)(x-\beta^{-j})=x^2-x(\beta^j+\beta^{-j})+1
$$
has coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_{32}$ for all $j=1,2,3,4,5$. This means that over
$\mathbb{F}_{32}$ the polynomial $\phi_{11}(x)$ splits into a product of five irreducible quadratic factors. The same factorization obviously is there, whenever $\gcd(n,10)=5$.

Comment: This is very sketchy for a person new to finite fields - sorry about that. I will gladly answer questions but only tomorrow. It's past my bedtime.